# Add to Favourite List example - working but with performance issues

Tags: react.js, callback, memoization, firebase

I am building a small framework for e-commerce or blog app using `React`.

One of the features of this framework is an "Add to Favourite List" function.

The app tree works as follow :

`App` file stores the `selectedItem` chosen by the `Menu`, and then `App` dispatches this `selectedItem` to a `displayCategoryItems`, which is the central view of the app.

The data is managed by the state provided by the `useHistory` hook, so I'm not using a classical `props` data management.

Once data ID is passed on to `displayCategoryItems`, it's being fetched on `Firestore` using an `async` function.

Data retrieved is passed to a `List` component which loops through the `Firestore` object and makes the data readable, and creates as much `Item` subcomponents as necessary in the display area using `forEach`.

Each `Item` has a function inherited from `App` which allows to add this `Item` to the favs (favourite) array state in `App`.

**There might be a performance issue, though** :

Each time an `Item` is being added to the `favs` state, it causes rerenders of `displayCategoryItems` and `List`, and also to all the `Item` in it, which can be problematic since the list of `Item` can be potentially huge.

I thought about wrapping the `handleFavs` function in a `useCallback`, but if I do so, the function loses its ability to check whether the `Item` name is already in the favs, which is not good, since it allows to add the item multiple times, and it does not prevent the multiple rerenders of `Item` anyway.

Here's the code :

App

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Menu from "./menu";
import "./main.css";
import MenuData from "./menuData";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from "./footer";
import Header from "./header";
import DisplayCategoryItems from "./displayCategoryItems";

function App() {

  const [selectedItem, setMenuItem] = useState(null)
  const [favs, setFavs] = useState([])

  const handleMenuItem = useCallback((menuItem) => {
    setMenuItem(menuItem)
  }, [])

  const handleFavs = (newFav) => {
    if (favs.indexOf(newFav) > -1) {
      return;
    } else {
      setFavs(previousFavs => [...previousFavs, newFav])
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header
          handleMenuItem={handleMenuItem} 
        ></Header>
        <Menu 
          // data for menu comes in an object stored locally : MenuData
          items={MenuData}
          handleMenuItem={handleMenuItem} 
          // for giving CSS style to the selected menuItem
          selectedItem={selectedItem}
        ></Menu>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route path = "/menu/:categoryItem/" exact render = {() => 
                <DisplayCategoryItems
                  handleFavs={handleFavs}
                ></DisplayCategoryItems>}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

displayCategoryItems child of App

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { collection, getDocs, where, query } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from "./firebase-config";
import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import Liste from "./liste";

const DisplayCategoryItems = (props) => {

    const [categoryItemData, setCategoryData] = useState([])

    const history = useHistory()

    const getCategoryData = async () => {
        const queryCategories = collection(db, "items")
        let data = query(queryCategories, where("category", "==", history.location.state.entry))
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(data);
        setCategoryData(querySnapshot)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategoryData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div 
                id="displayCategoryItems" 
                className="display"
            >
                <Liste
                    data={categoryItemData}
                    handleFavs={props.handleFavs}
                ></Liste>
            </div>
            {console.log("Display Category Items")}
        </>
    )
};

export default DisplayCategoryItems;
```

List child of DisplayCategoryItems

```
import React from "react";
import Item from "./item";

const Liste = (props) => {

    const categoryItemDataList=[]
    props.data.forEach(doc => {
       // items can have several different packaging, hence this For loop
        for (let i = 0; i < doc.data().packaging.length; i++) {
            categoryItemDataList.push(
                <Item 
                    key={doc.data().name + i}
                    data={doc.data()}
                    handleFavs={props.handleFavs}
                ></Item >
            )
        }
    })

    return (
        <>  <div>
                {categoryItemDataList}
            </div>
            {console.log("Liste")}
        </>
    )
};

export default Liste;
```

Item component for List

```
import React from "react";

const Item = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div 
                className="item"
            >
                <div
                    className="itemBody"
                >{props.data.name}</div>
                <table className="ItemFooter">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
///////// favs are added here ////////////////
                            <th className="ItemddToFav" onClick={() => props.handleFavs(props.data.name)}></th>
                            <th className="ItemBuy">Buy</th>
                            <th className="ItemRight"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            {console.log("Item")}
        </>
    )
}

export default Item;
```

And the other tree of the project, the Menu

Menu child of App

```
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "./menuItem";

const Menu = (props) => {

    const menuItemList = []

    for (const [entry, value] of Object.entries(props.items)) {
        menuItemList.push(
            <MenuItem 
                key={entry}
                entry={entry}
                handleMenuItem={props.handleMenuItem} 
                value={value.value} 
                classN={props.selectedItem === entry ? "menuItem selected" : "menuItem"}
            ></MenuItem>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>  <div id="menuWrapper">
                <table id="menu">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {menuItemList}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            {console.log("menu")}
        </>
    )
};

export default React.memo(Menu);
```

MenuItem component for Menu

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const MenuItem = (props) => {

    const history = useHistory()

    const handleClick = () => {
        props.handleMenuItem(props.entry)
        history.push(`/menu/${props.entry}`)
        history.replace({
            state : props.entry
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <th
                onClick={() => handleClick()} 
                className={props.classN}
            >{props.value}</th>
            {console.log("MenuItem's render")}
        </>
    )
};

export default React.memo(MenuItem);
```

Anyone has an idea on how to stop these multiple rerendering while managing the `favs` state properly ?